# Uploading large files on R shiny tool hosted on server

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

When running on local, I can upload large files in no time by reading the path but on the server where I am trying to get the file from client's system, I have no option of reading the path, so I have to use fileinput function instead.
But the problem is, It takes a lot of time for uploading large files. Is there an alternate to fileinput that I can use on the server.

Thanks

Comment: You can play around with different file types to try and reduce the space complexity of the read process. Alternatively have the app read from a database instead of a flat-file. Ultimately, though, large files will take a long time to read!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing your max request size. Maybe it should solve your issue.

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 60*1024^2)
```

With the above code it accepts files upto 60MB.

Comment: Yes, Actually I have increased the max size to 500mb. Problem is that it takes too much time to upload files around 500mb

Comment: What is the type of file?

Comment: Currently I am trying to upload .csv file